Can the rules of existential elimination and introduction be derived from the rules of universal elimination and introduction?
In my understanding, an existentially quantified predicate ∃xFx is defined as ~∀x~Fx but in introductory logic texts the elimination and introduction rules for existential and universal quantifiers are given independently. Is it possible to show that the existential rules can be derived from the universal ones?

Yes, in classical logic it is possible to show that the existential rules are derivable from the universal and negation rules, in the sense that it is possible to find a derivation using just those latter rules with the premise of the existential rules as the assumption and the conclusion of the rule as the end formula of the derivation, each with the formulas rewritten in terms of ∀ and ~:
1. Fa (assumption)   
| 2. ∀x~Fx (assumption)   
| 3. ~Fa (∀ elim. 2)   
| 4. ⊥ (~ elim. 1+3)  
5. ~∀x~Fx (~ intro. 2-4)

Analogous for the elimination rule. The same would work vice versa too, treating ∀xFx as syntactic sugar for ~∃x~Fx and deriving the universal rules from the existential and negation rules.
If you treat the existential quantifier as just syntactic sugar for what is actually ~∀x~Fx, then indeed the existential rules can be done away with. But most books treat both quantifiers as primitive, and in any case it is in practice more convenient to have the shorter formulas and rules available.

Thank you. Could you show the derivation of ∃-elimination? I can't work out how to remove the negation.

For existential elimination you'll additionally need reductio ad absurdum to remove a negation. In a subproof assume ~C, derive a contradiction first with C obtained from the given assumption Fa, from that obtain ∀x~Fx by negation and universal rules, yielding another contraction with the major premise of the existential elimination rule, which finally allows you to derive the conclusion.

@CGULL Hi there, not sure if I am misconceiving your question, but depending on what you mean, one may add that such equivalences are only possible in some systems, usually needing a double negation rule or law of excluded middle. (And, in constructive mathematics/logic, the negation of some universal sentence is not 'as good as', or identical, to the corresponding existence sentence.)
